# How to make ui-mask return the $viewValue to the model, instead of $modelValue?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using `ui-mask` on an input, so the user can type in a date:

```html
 <input type="text" ui-mask="19/39/2999" ng-model="inicio">
```

(the 1, 3 and 2 are some extra masks I put so it will allow only 0 to 1, 0 to 3 and 2 to 3, respectively)

The problem is, I initialize the input using `dateFilter` on my controller

```js
 $scope.inicio = dateFilter((new Date), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

The input shows the correct value for the today date for example `06/13/2013`. The problem is when I change the input to `05/13/2013`, the `$scope.inicio` model will contain `05132013` (no formatting at all), and I have no clue how to make it use the `$viewValue` instead of the `$modelValue`, can it be done?

Comment: The answer is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116730/how-to-access-the-ngmodelcontroller-from-inside-the-controller-without-a-form-a

Answer (score 1):

**What I did was just adding an attribute to control wether you use viewValue or the Value.**

And changing the scripts is no trouble at all, it requires about **`5`** lines of code.

### **Here's how:**

- I will try to show the context of the code additions as best as possible, by providing a small view of the above and below code.

First add the variable to the top of

```
return function uiMaskLinkingFunction(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
    var maskProcessed = false, eventsBound = false,
    maskCaretMap, maskPatterns, maskPlaceholder, maskComponents,
    //... Ton of varaibles...

    var useViewValue; // <----- ADD THIS
```

Later on in the code, you find the Formatter and Parser functions:

```
      function formatter(fromModelValue){
        /*formatter code*/
      }

      function parser(fromViewValue){
        // parser code...
        if (value === '' && controller.$error.required !== undefined) {
          controller.$setValidity('required', false);
        }
        // ADD useViewValue code START
        if (useViewValue) 
            value = value.length ? maskValue(value) : '';
        // ADD useViewValue code END
        return isValid ? value : undefined;
      }
```

And finally, you just need to add an observer to the attribute value:

```
      iAttrs.$observe('uiMask', initialize);

      // ADD useViewValue code START
      iAttrs.$observe('uiMaskUseViewvalue', function (useVVal) {
          useViewValue = useVVal == 'true';
      });
      // ADD useViewValue code END
      iAttrs.$observe('placeholder', initPlaceholder);
```

**Implement it in the HTML also**

```
<input type="text" ui-mask="19/39/2999" ui-mask-use-viewvalue="true" ng-model="inicio">
```

Comment: yes, but instead of messing with the library code, you should write another directive that works concurrently with that directly, that means, creating the `uiMaskUserViewvalue` directive, and applying your parsers inside of that

Comment: @pocesar I could either `a.` Do that, and sit down for an hour or something, making that probably work, or `b.` use 2 minutes fixing an already good masker, to have the functionality I need. I'm not working on a hobby project, every minute I spend is costing money. And reinventing the wheel has no business value.

Comment: @André Snede Hansen  I'm having this EXACT same problem, while this code fixed the issue.  I'm curious, when will this change be available in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Angular.UI.Utils/  ?????  This way the minified version comes along with it

Comment: @denas Its still an open pull-request: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/pull/199 and thats as far as I have been able to take it. If you want the feature you would need to go on GitHub and help get it taken into the module.

Comment: @denas Also if you just want it minified, you can do that yourself quite easily, fx. with Web Essentials.

Comment: @André Snede Hansen  My concern is when the next version on the angularui / angularui-utils is release this will go back to broke because a different attribute will be used to indicate the viewvalue ie... it won't be "ui-mask-use-viewvalue" anymore.  Is webessentials what you use to minify the script?  I did notice these changes seem to be in github as posted here  https://github.com/Snede/ui-utils/commit/7485a1db0c78a2afd970927b88e06eb3b0bc4654

Comment: @denas I share your concern, and theres not much we/I can do, unless they take the pull-request. The changes in the link are suggested and made by me, but they have not been accepted yet, and I don't have time at the moment to change the code to the changes they suggest. But I welcome anyone to do it.

Comment: @André Snede Hansen Thanks for the code.  How do you see the code changes they've suggested over the ones you've made?

Comment: The have just written what they thought should be different, I haven't changed the code yet, its all the thread in the link I gave you.

Comment: @André Snede Hansen modelViewValue is in your codebase and that attribute actually already does what you are attempting to do in the above code and that changes seems to be in the master branch.  Thanks for your help!