# How to access the $ngModelController from inside the Controller without a Form and without a Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Maybe it's a rookie mistake, but I can't seem to access the `$scope.model`'s `$ngModelController` so I can grab the `$viewValue` from it.

I have an input without a form (im using ui-mask directive):

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="inicio" name="inicio" ui-mask="99/99/9999">
```

```js
// inside my controller
$scope.inicio = dateFilter((new Date).getTime(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

ui-mask set the $modelValue a different value than $viewValue, making it hard to send formatted data to the server. When the `$scope.inicio` model changes, the value is a date without slashes, like `01012014`. So I need to be able to get the controller for that input, but without having to wrap it in a form, and have to use `$scope.myForm.inicio.$viewValue`. It MUST be possible...

Things I know I can do, but seems hacky, there must be a simpler way:

- Put the element inside a form and access it through `$scope.myForm.input.$viewValue`
- Get the element data using jQuery `$('input[name="inicio"]').data('$ngModelController');`
- Get the element using `angular.element('input[name="inicio"]').controller('ngModel');`
- Create a directive, put it in the input, and update my scope model with it

```js
app.directive('viewValue', function(){
  return {
    priority: 10,
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
      scope.$watch(attrs.viewValue, function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue !== oldValue){
          scope[attrs.viewValue] = controller.$viewValue;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" ui-mask="99/99/9999" ng-model="inicio" view-value="inicio">
```

Comment: Why is putting the element inside the form tag hacky?

Comment: I don't need a form there, just the input, makes no sense to me having to use 2 models, for one 'simple' thing, that is, access the `ngModelController` on that element, plus having an input without a form is perfectly fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the directive alternative.  Essentially the `ui-mask` directive isn't doing what you want, so you might as well write your own directive.

You shouldn't have to pass `inicio` to your `view-value` directive.  Instead, add your own parser to `ngModelCtrl.$parsers`.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556249/215945

Comment: the value that is getting to the parser is the already modified date without formatting. the directive shouldn't know what the format should be... what else can I do?

Comment: ah, I see, I just return the controller.$viewValue from it, instead of trying to transform the input text. nice!