# Grab $viewValue from controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

How do I access $ngmodel.$viewValue in the controller?  I have a ui-mask and it's not producing the correct value for the ng-model so I want to extract the value I see from my input field.

Comment: Might be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116730/how-to-access-the-ngmodelcontroller-from-inside-the-controller-without-a-form-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if your input is wrapped inside a form which has name attribute and input field itself has name attribute you can get it in controller.

Say

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="myInput"/>
</form>
```

You can access this form in your controller using

`$scope.myForm.myInput.$viewValue`

`myInput` is an instance of `ngModelController`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom directive that requires `ngModel` thus gaining access to the `ngModelController`. Then you can access the **[`$viewValue`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24viewValue)**, the **[`$modelValue`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24modelValue)** and a few more really useful stuff, such as **[`$parsers`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24parsers)**, **[`$formatters`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24formatters)** etc.
You can read all about it in **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)**.

E.g.:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            // Here you have access to:
            //modelCtrl.$viewValue
            //modelCtrl.$modelValue
            //modelCtrl.$parsers
            //modelCtrl.$formatters
            // e.g.:
            $modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                // The $viewValue has changed. Let's just log it
                // and pass it on unaffected...
                console.log(viewValue);
                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```